# Sorting data in PHP for a single elimination tournament display in HTML

Tags: php, sorting, data-structures

I have a table that has the following columns and fields:

```
userid  round faceoff username
------------------------------
  1       1     2      Kevin
  3       1     1      Steve
  4       1     3      Jake
  9       1     4      Sam
  1       2     1      Kevin
  9       2     2      Sam
  1       3     1      Kevin
```

The round are the columns and faceoff are the rows. Thus round 1 has a max of faceoff 4, and round 2 has a faceoff max of 2, etc.

I want to display the data on users screens like so (basic HTML):

```
Round 1      Round 2     Final (round 3)
 Steve
              Kevin
 Kevin
                          Kevin
 Jake
              Sam
 Sam
```

Here is what I have so far:

`$tor` is the array from MySQL, I `var_dump()` it and everything is there. I'm just having issues with the `for` loops:

```
for ($u=0;$u<=$torindex;$u++)
{
    for ($r=1;$r<=$torindex+1;$r++)
    {
        if ($tor[$u]['round'] == $r) 
        {
            for ($f=1;$f<=$torindex+1;$f++)
            {
                if ($tor[$u]['faceoff'] == $f) $placement[$r][$f] = $tor[$u]['userid'].":".$tor[$u]['username'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where do I go from here?

Comment: What's the problem? Have you tried it and come across a problem?

Comment: I can't really think of a way to sort it.

Comment: right, what do you want and what did you try? do you want to sort the records by faceoff asc and to display them in a different column in a table depending on the value of round?

Comment: where is this data coming from? is it from a database, so you could use `order by`? or is it somewhere else?

Comment: I updated my answer with the loops I'm using.

Answer (score 1):

For each row in your data table, you can find right row in HTML table to display it using this equation:

```
rowNum = pow(2, round - 1) + (faceoff - 1) * pow(2, round);
```

so this should work in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM tournament ORDER BY pow(2, round - 1) + (faceoff - 1) * pow(2, round);
```

Comment: just tried it, and got the result: Steve round 1 faceoff 1, Kevin round 2 faceoff 1, Kevin round 1 faceoff 2, Kevin round 3 faceoff 1, Jake round 1 faceoff 3, Sam round 2 faceoff 2, Sam round 1 faceoff 4. Seems about right to me, can you elaborate how this is off? Perhaps I don't really understand your problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Structure

I have used the [Knockout tournament scheduler](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4718-PHP-Manage-knockout-tournament-games.html) class by Nicholas Mossor Rathmann for this task in the past with great success. Given teams/players it will calculate the ties and eliminations based on the matches final score.

### Output

For CSS/HTML output instead of the GD generated image the class gives you I used One Fork's [jQuery & JSON to draw single-elimination tournament bracket](http://whileonefork.blogspot.com/2010/10/jquery-json-to-draw-elimination-single.html) with some modifications for IE compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Sort it by round like you have it and as you cycle through the rows keep track of the current round. If the row's round is not equal to the current round you know to move to the right. You can close and start a `div` or `ul` and float them to the left.

http://jsfiddle.net/RxDrd/

Comment: Will this work if you do not know the total number of rounds when you write the CSS?

Comment: @Treffynnon - yes, you can just add some extra css to cover the max rounds you will have and it will work.

Comment: But you would still have to know that up front, which is unrealistic.

Comment: you are going to know the max rounds, obviously. if for some crazy reason you didnt, and you didnt want to just add a few extra lines of css to cover it, you could output css with php and your problem is solved.